# Print opposite triangle recursion c++ in 1 function

Tags: c++, recursion

I wonder if it is possible to print an opposite triangle (by "*") recursively using 1 function only.

for example
for the given base n=4
it should print

```
*****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
```

I am a beginner, but I know how to program 1 recursive function for

```
*****
***
**
*
```

and one for

```
*
**
***
****
```

but is it possible to program 2 opposite triangles in 1 function?
Might be a stupid question that the answer of it is no- but I've been trying for an hour now and I could'nt make it.
I will be very thankful if you can let me know if it's even possible or not.

EDIT: My code for 2 different functions:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printOppositeriangle(int n);
void printOppositeriangle2(int n);

void main()
{
    int n = 5;
    printOppositeriangle(n);
    printOppositeriangle2(n);

}
void printOppositeriangle(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
        printOppositeriangle(n - 1);
    }
}
void printOppositeriangle2(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return;

    else
        printOppositeriangle2(n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "*";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I think the solution should be a tweak of what you already have. Please share the code about your 2 solutions.

Comment: The @John answer is correct, but in your code here you are missing { } to make a block in the else part of your printOppositeTriangle2(). It works, but it's not properly written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple enough, make your recursive call in the *middle*, before and after print out a row of asterisks.

```
void print(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << '*';
    cout << '\n';
    if (n > 1)
        print(n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << '*';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Untested code.